# align caption of figure in list of figure

Tags: captions, tocloft

I have a figure in LaTeX with a caption that doesn't fit into one line, e.g.

```
\begin{figure}
 \includegraphics{}
\caption{This is a very long caption that does not fit into one line}
\end{figure}
```

The resulting PDF looks as follows in list of figure:

```
Figure 1: This is a very long caption that does not fit
into one line
```

I would like the second line of the caption be either aligned with the start of the caption (not the text "Figure 1") to make it look like

```
Figure 1: This is a very long caption that does not fit
          into one line
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use adequate caption settings. For example:

```
    \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}% <-- for more options, read caption manual
\usepackage[hang]{caption}% <-- for more options, read caption manual

\setlength\textwidth{77mm}

%\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}% just for see figure
%\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\listoffigures

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}
\caption{This is a very long caption that does not fit into one line}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Edit (1):**
I added a figure below. For It generation I added `graphicx` package and use `preview` package for better seeing the picture.

[image]

Is this what you looking for?

**Edit (2):**
Now I see, that you like format list of figures. In document class `book` this is default features (but without of names `Figure` before figure numbers). And, as told in comment, provide MWE, which show your problem.

Comment: but it don't work for me . i also use `hyperref`package. i think it make problem.

Comment: Then provide your MWE. I haven't Crystal ball. Given MWE work for me.

Comment: i want do this for list of figure not for caption of figure.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this e.g. with `titletoc`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{titletoc,geometry}
\geometry{textwidth=10cm,showframe}

\contentsmargin{0.5cm}
\titlecontents{figure}
  [1.7cm]
  {}
  {\makebox[0pt][r]{%
      \makebox[1.7cm][l]{Figure~\thecontentslabel:}%
    }%
  }
  {\hspace{-1.7cm}}
  {\titlerule*[6pt]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
 \centering\rule{4cm}{1.5cm}
 \caption{This is a very long caption that does not fit into one line}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
 \centering\rule{4cm}{1.5cm}
 \caption{This is the next very long caption that does not fit into
   one line}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik - You should ping the OP `;-)`

Comment: My hypothesis is that OP is not responsive. He has been contacted before, alas...